What should I do with a question if the answers all answer a subquestion that's more useful than the original question was?
A while ago, I was looking to do X. I thought that I might be able to solve the problem by doing Y, but was also open to other potential answers. So, in order to avoid the XY problem, I asked a question along the lines of "How do I do X? I think I might be able to do it via doing Y, but I can't figure out how to do Y either".
When I asked the question, I ended up with a couple of answers explaining how to do Y, together with some comments doubting whether Y was actually a good way to achieve X.
The answers for how to achieve Y are non-obvious, and may be generally useful. But a search asking how to do Y doesn't turn up any relevant results. As I understand it, Stack Overflow's model is partially to try to help people with their immediate problems, but also partially to try to build an FAQ – and the question I asked is probably not a very good FAQ question, because Y is more generally useful than X is. For other people with similar problems, they'd be much better off with a question "how do I do Y?" than "how do I do X?" (because they probably aren't trying to do X) – additionally, the existing answers might not be ideal for the actual question I asked, "how do I do X?", due to the doubts about whether Y is actually a good way to achieve X.
So I can see three main options:

Leave everything as it is.
This means that people trying to do X will get potentially bad advice based on my own attempts to solve the problem, and people trying to do Y probably won't find the answers explaining how to do Y.
Edit the question to be "How do I do Y?", giving X as an example (so that the existing answers still make sense).
This would be the most immediately useful for people who were searching Stack Overflow for answers to their question.
One drawback is that the answers would lose some of their context; another is that editing the question to no longer be about X would discourage people who knew the best way to do X to give a non-Y-related answer (if any exist).
Create a new question, "How do I do Y?".
The problem here is that, despite not being a duplicate question, the answers would be duplicates of the existing "How do I do X?" question – and it is unclear who should be the person to post them. (For example, if I ask that question, should I copy over / paraphrase the answers from the existing question? I could link to them to give credit, but it seems wrong to effectively steal the upvotes from them, as a "how do I do Y?" question is likely to be much more popular. Or should I wait for it to be answered again? — but that seems like a waste of everyone's time.)

Which of these is the best approach?
(A related existing question: I found an answer but the question was very different from mine. How can I make the answer easier to find for other people?, which is for a similar situation, but written from the point of view of someone who is trying to do Y – and it isn't clear whether the situation is the same, nor does the existing answer help me figure out what to do in this one.)

If you asked how to do X and thought about doing Y, but didn't know how, and explained what both X and Y are and got answers on how to do Y, is that also not an answer that Y is the correct way to do X? If you want other methods you could always add a bounty explicitly stating in the bounty notice you're also looking for alternatives to Y.

I would opt for leaving things the way they are but perhaps just edit the existing title to include that nuance (i.e. "How to do Y to do X?") if its not too wordy. That leaves room for more generalized Q&As to exist while being referenceable to both.

@ThomA: I thought that Y was a valid way to do X at the time I asked the question, but at least one commenter disagreeed (but didn't know of any alternative ways to do X).

Don't mention Y when your question is X. Mention what is relevant to X. Fuzzing your question by vaguely relating to Y just leads to poor answers involving Y. I don't have any sympathy for Y answerers if you clarify a post to remove specious & content, because the post clearly wasn't a clear question re Y & they shouldn't have answered.

@philipxy OP should mention what they have tried though, and Y was one such thing.

Regarding downvotes, I asked a similar question some time ago and it got similarly downvoted (more than yours, but still got 8 upvotes as well). My guess is that people don’t want to do anything about such questions. I suppose that, ideally, the question should be split in two, moving each answer to the right question, but we don’t have the tools for that (even the mods).

If you're worried about getting undue credit (e.g. votes) with option three (new question "How do I do Y?"), you can make your answer to the new question a community-wiki.

The safest approach, in the sense of being the one where you are least likely to make anything worse and least likely to make anyone cross with you, is to leave everything as it is. You certainly have the right to do this.
But you are quite reasonably not happy with this outcome. You reckon this leaves the state of Stack Overflow worse than it could be, because it leaves us with a question that primarily asks how to do X and answers that answer how to do Y, a situation that poorly serves both people searching for X and people searching for Y. And it's quite right that you care about this; Stack Overflow's primary purpose is to be a knowledge base that people search using Google (or occasionally other search engines or Stack Overflow's own search), and if you can tell that your question in its current state is failing to improve that knowledge base, or actively making it worse by misleading people who see it in their search results about what its answers will contain, then that's a problem it'd be useful to fix.
Contra others here, I think that if you're confident you can improve the Q&A for future readers, it's fine to very carefully go ahead and do so. I'm glad, in fact, that even as a low-rep user you care enough about making your questions valuable resources for future readers that you'd consider doing this! Just be aware that you are doing something that many members of the community frown upon and counsel against, so please, whenever you decide to do this, do your absolute best job of it and try and make sure it's as clear as possible that you are leaving the question better than it was before. Principles to keep in mind when making these kind of edits:

Don't touch a thing until you have carefully read every answer; this is a prerequisite for being able to judge everything else.
Make sure the new question you're going to end up with is at least as good a question as the original.
Consider whether the existing answers you've got are really just bad answers and a better course of action would be to downvote them and leave your question as-is. (I'm not necessarily asserting that this is likely, but it seems worth considering in a situation where you asked how to do X and got multiple answers not addressing how to do X at all.)
Don't substantially invalidate any existing answers.

"Invalidating" here includes anything that makes the answer seem pointless, redundant, or stupid when it wasn't originally, not just things that make it outright incorrect in inapplicable.


Try not to invalidate even trivial parts of existing answers. If you must do so, then edit the answers too to fix or remove the bit you invalidated, explaining yourself in the edit summary.

Corollary: If the question edit you want to make would invalidate even some small bit of an existing answer, and you don't yet have full editing privileges and so can't fix it without your edits going through review, then don't make the edit to the question. Hold off until you've got 2000 rep and can fix the answers too.


Pay particular attention to your question's title, and make sure it ends up consistent with the body. It is the most important part of the question. It will frequently be the only part of your question that someone searching reads before they click through and scroll down to the answers.
Explain yourself in your edit summary.
If the situation is too messy to be able to do the above, give up. (Or, rarely and only if it's a highly-viewed question that you think it's worthwhile to do something radical and unconventional with, propose a course of action for that specific question on Meta and see what others think. As an example of how far it's possible to go when no other remedy will work, here's a case where we settled on a consensus of the mods outright deleting some previously valid answers just to let us narrow down the scope of a question.)

A more general remark: there are a bunch of kinds of edits - e.g. ones that change the scope of an existing question like you contemplate here, or ones that modify code in someone else's question - that fall in an awkward intersection where they're often the most useful thing you can do to clean up existing content and make it more valuable to future readers and they're also frequently discouraged or characterised as outright forbidden on Meta. If you care about presenting useful content to future readers, you're going to feel that tension constantly.
If you choose to dabble in doing this, or making any other kinds of controversial edits, then just please put in the effort needed to ensure it is indisputably clear at the end of the process that you made the page better and didn't damage anyone else's existing work in the process.

I suggest that you ask a new question about how to do Y, and then write an answer to your own question by explaining what you've learned about how to do Y from your original question.  Provide attribution to the relevant answers on your original question.  I think this best serves the mission of building up a high-quality knowledge base that will be useful to others.

You could even ask that the question be closed as a duplicate.  As long as the roomba doesn't delete it, it still serves as a search target and provides a link to the answers you found useful.

To me this comes down to the case of a poor question with potentially useful answers.
I don't upvote the question (or sometimes even downvote it) and only upvote helpful answers.
Of course, the ideal is for helpful answers to appear on good questions. The voting system is how we steer for this eventual situation.

You should not edit a question to ask something completely different. Asking for X was your original intent and it should stay that way. There might be users who are investigating in the problem right now just to find out that the question is now about something completely different. Changing a question dramatically might be even considered vandalism, specially when you are question-banned or want to bypass the bounty-time-limit. When the answers don't actually answer the question X, because they answer the question Y, they should be downvoted as not useful.
You can create a new question asking for Y if you think that would be a good question for Stack Overflow. Then it would attract answers for Y.

My problem is that the original question already has answers for Y – if I ask a new question, should I do anything to "copy those answers over"?

@ais523: I'm not sure of the best way to do it, but you could "copy over" the answer with proper attribution and make it community wiki.

@ais523 - If you are not getting answers to a portion of your question there must be a reason. Changing the question to remove that portion is frowned upon. So you should either look to clarify that portion, so someone can answer your question in its entirety, or just leave it alone and accept an answer if you’re satisfied with the answer you have already received. Your description of the answers make it sound they are not the greatest answers.

@SecurityHound: In this case, when you're able to do Y, there's code that trivially appears to do X using it, so the answers don't dwell on that point much – but there's some debate about whether the implementation of X in terms of Y is correct or not. That wouldn't matter on a question about how to do Y, and the answers are a good explanation of how to do Y.

You should not edit a question to ask something completely different because it invalidates the answers. But in this case it makes the answers more valid, not less. Good advice comes with a rationale so you can tell when it becomes bad advice - Raymond Chen.
